# Mongo Map-Reduce - Top Venues By Users in a Radius

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, geospatial

I'm having issues with my MapReduce function - the goal is to get the list of top venues, within a certain lat/lng, group by `vid`, ordered by distinct `user_id`.

Here is a sample data set:

```
  { "_id" : ObjectId("51f9234feb97ff0700000046"), "checkin_id" : 39286249, "created_at" : ISODate("2013-07-31T14:47:11Z"), "loc" : { "lat" : 42.3672, "lon" : -86.2681 }, "icv" : 1, "ipv" : 1, "vid" : 348442, "user_id" : 151556, "bid" : 9346, "pid" : 549 }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("51f9234b488fff0700000006"), "checkin_id" : 39286247, "created_at" : ISODate("2013-07-31T14:47:07Z"), "loc" : { "lat" : 55.6721, "lon" : 12.5576 }, "icv" : 1, "ipv" : 1, "vid" : 3124, "user_id" : 472486, "bid" : 7983, "pid" : 2813 }
  ...
```

Here is my map function:

```
map1 = function() {
  var tempDoc = {};
  tempDoc[this.user_id] = 1;

  emit(this.vid, {
     users: tempDoc,
     count: 1
  });
}
```

And reduce:

```
reduce1 = function(key, values) {

    var summary = {
     users: {},
     total: 0
    };

    values.forEach(function (doc) {

       // increment total for every value
       summary.total += doc.count;

       // Object.extend() will only add keys from the right object that do not exist on the left object
      Object.extend(summary.users, doc.user);

    });


   return summary;
};
```

My geo_query:

```
var d = Date("2013-07-31T14:47:11Z");
var geo_query = {loc: {$near: [40.758318,-73.952985], $maxDistance: 25}, "icv":1, "created_at": {$gte: d}};
```

And finally the mapReduce query:

```
var res = db.myColelction.mapReduce(map1, reduce1,  { out : { inline : 1 }, query : geo_query });
```

The results that are returned are matching the reduce function, but not hitting the finalize1 function:

```
...
{
    "_id" : 609096,
    "value" : {
        "users" : {
            "487586" : 1
        },
        "count" : 1
    }
},
{
    "_id" : 622448,
    "value" : {
        "users" : {
            "313755" : 1,
            "443180" : 1
        },
        "total" : 4
    }
},
...
```

At this point, I think I have a good result set, but the `$near` function only scans 100 of the venues that are nearby, and I want to scan ALL venues (all documents that match this radius (25m), and look at all venues - group them, and count unique users in that time period. I've search around, looked at documentation and I'm not sure of a solution. Any takers?

The final result for me would be sort and limit the result by the "total" attribute. Ideally, I would want to to sort by total desc and limit 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do the following. First of all, you have the coordinates the wrong way around. MongoDB wants `longitude, latitude`, preferably in GeoJSON format:

```
loc: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-73.952985, 40.758318] },
```

MongoDB **does not care** about the `lat` and `lon` field names, and will **ignore** them.

But you should also avoid Map/Reduce as it's slow and complex. Instead, we can use the Aggregation Framework to do something similar:

```
db.so.aggregate( [
    // search for all the (well, million) venues within **250**km
    { $geoNear: {
        near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-73.952985, 40.758318] },
        spherical: true,
        distanceField: 'd',
        maxDistance: 250 * 1000,
        limit: 1000000
    } },
    // find only the items where icv=1
    { $match: { icv: 1 } },
    // group by venue and user
    { $group: { 
        _id: { vid: '$vid', user_id: '$user_id' }, 
        count: { $sum: 1 } } 
    },
    // then regroup by just venue:
    { $group: { 
        _id: '$_id.vid', 
        users: { $addToSet: { user_id: '$_id.user_id', count: '$count' } }, 
        total: { $sum: '$count' } 
    } },
    // now we sort by "total", desc:
    { $sort: { 'total': -1 } },
    // and limit by 15:
    { $limit: 15 }
] );
```

I've used `$geoNear` as first stage, and the match on `$icv` as second stage as it is likely that the `$geoNear` index is going to be a lot better than the `$icv` one (as I guess, it will only have the values 0 or 1 anyway).

Please note that for this example, I used 250 km (250 * 1000 meters) and not 25 km.

With the following input:

```
db.so.insert( { "_id" : ObjectId("51f9234feb97ff0700000046"), "loc" : { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ -73.2681, 40.3672 ] }, "vid" : 348442, "user_id" : 151556 } );
db.so.insert( { "_id" : ObjectId("51f9234b488fff0700000006"), "loc" : { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ -73.5576, 40.6721 ] }, "vid" : 3124, "user_id" : 472486 } );
db.so.insert( { "_id" : ObjectId("51f92345488fff0700000006"), "loc" : { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ -73.5576, 40.6721 ] }, "vid" : 3124, "user_id" : 47286 } );
db.so.insert( { "_id" : ObjectId("52f92345488fff0700000006"), "loc" : { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ -73.5576, 40.6721 ] }, "vid" : 3124, "user_id" : 47286 } );
```

You get as result:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 3124,
            "users" : [
                { "user_id" : 472486, "count" : 1 },
                { "user_id" : 47286, "count" : 2 }
            ],
            "total" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : 348442,
            "users" : [
                { "user_id" : 151556, "count" : 1 }
            ],
            "total" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

There is only one difference with your wanted output, and that is that the user_id is not a key for the count, but an extra field in a sub-document. In general you can't change a value to a key or key to a value with the aggregation framework.

Comment: Derick - this is a great answer. I only one questions: I need to add another restriction on the initial query, so I need to query (everything within X,Y with icv = 1) - how does that work in your formula?

Comment: You can add a match as a first stage, which works as a normal query. I'll update the answer to match everything with icv=1.

Comment: Last couple of question - what happens there are that many records out the 1m in the initial param? Does it error? The final result for me would be sort and limit the result by the "total" attribute. Ideally, I would want to to sort by total desc and limit 15. I was going to do this after the query is over, but if can be done - that would helpful. Possible?

Comment: No, it doesn't error. It will just give you the first million. If that's still not enough, add a 0 ;-). Sorting is most definitely possible. I've updated your question and my answer to include it.

Comment: Derick - and finally - what type of index would this query require? If  I wanted to the same thing with bid that we are doing with vid - would I need to two 2dsphere indexes? I wasn't aware that that was possible?

Comment: Just the first operator in a pipeline uses an index, so a ``2dsphere`` index on ``loc`` will suffice

Comment: So I don't need any index on any other index besides the 2dsphere on the "loc"?

Comment: Right, at least not for this aggregation pipeline workflow. If you query in other ways, you might of course need indexes for that.

Comment: Is there anything else needed to fully answer this question?

Comment: Derick - working with it over the weekend and it's performing very nicely. I guess I would just need to add an addition match query (such  as created_at) to only show those results that are $gt X. Do I just add another match, and what index would be required?

Comment: You can just extend the current ``$match``: ``{ $match: { icv: 1, created_at: { $gt: X } } }`` — just like a find. Indexes are only used for the first operator, which is ``$geoNear`` so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I have one final question - how can I change the "total" property to show the total distinct users and not $sum of the count property?

Comment: I think *that* you can't do all in one go - sorry. You'll have to re-create an aggregation pipeline by doing a group on them.

Comment: So just add another $group by user_id?

Answer (score 0):

You say the function only scans 100 venues. My understanding of near is that it will scan the entire collection and only return the nearest 100.

Copy pasted from the documentation of [$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/):

Note: You can further limit the number of results using cursor.limit().
Specifying a batch size (i.e. batchSize()) in conjunction with queries that use the $near is not defined. See SERVER-5236 for more information.

Comment: Yes - but that's not I'm looking to do. I want it to GROUP by the venue_id and allow me to count unqiue users. If it only returns 100 entries (sorted by nearest to farest), so I don't have all the documents in the query to make the MapReduce - so I only have a subsection. I don't want to limit the number returned, so I want them all to go through the Map Reduce function.

Comment: In that case I personally wouldn't query by $near in your first query. I would process all the records in the mapreduce without distance restrictions and specify the out parameter of mapreduce to be a "reduced" collection then do a db.reduced.find({loc: {$near: [40.758318,-73.952985]}})